# MySQL timestamp default value invalid

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, timestamp

I'm trying to create a table with default timestamp on MYSQL 5.7.23 (phpmyadmin)

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
    id MEDIUMINT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01',
    updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

TIMESTAMP value has a range from '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC

so you should use

```
 created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01',
```

or as suggested  by  RaymondNijland

```
created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT 0
```

or change to

```
created_at datetime DEFAULT '1900-01-01 00:00:01',
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html

Comment: @RaymondNijland   correct  .. answer  uodated  with your suggestion too

Comment: Well i removed that comment because is wasn't sure after that when i read something in the manual. "With a constant, the default is the given value. In this case, the column has **no automatic properties** at all.  CREATE TABLE t1 (
  ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT 0,
  dt DATETIME DEFAULT 0
);"  source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01' //SAME ERROR

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong @mhrzn see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3fMq1XidpmmMbFGTHHb3U3/0) the demo's version is MySQL 5.7.22

Comment: does the above sql query run on your phpmyadmin ? im following this tutorial and it works fine on his machine.